# QPrinter image gets cut off when printing

Tags: python, printing, pyqt, qprinter, qprintpreviewdialog

I am attempting to print an image to a xerox printer in Qt. Using the following code I can print, however the image gets cut off to only the top 3rd of the page or so, when using `HighResolution` mode on the QPrinter. In `ScreenResolution` it works as expected, however the image is fairly low quality. Calling `printer.setResolution()` seems to have no effect on print quality whatsoever.

Strangely I can position text wherever I want in the QPainter and it will print just fine, it is specifically the image which gets cropped off. Also strange is that when I use a `QPrintPreviewDialog` all looks well, but the printed result is still cut off. Not sure where to go from here, I tried two different printers with the same issue.

FWIW I'm on Windows.

```
printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
printer.setResolution(1200) # doesn't seem to do much
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPagedPaintDevice.Legal)

dialog = QPrintDialog(printer)
dialog.exec_()
im = QtGui.QImage('path/to/image')
im = im.scaledToWidth(printer.pageRect().width(), QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.begin(printer)
painter.drawImage(0, 0, im)
painter.end()
```

Comment: I made a minor discovery. Scaling the painter by the difference between my image and the printer resolution seems to "fix" it. Of course now I have other issues when trying to draw with the scaled painter, namely my text is coming out jumbo size...

Comment: drawIamge or drawImage?

Comment: @eyllanesc right you are!